# C# 6.0 to < 6.0

Tags: c#

I need to convert the following code which is in `C# 6.0` to a lower version which works in .NET framework 4.5.

```
  public ImageCollection Strokes { get;  } = new ImageCollection();  //C# 6.0
```

How do i convert this?

Tried the below code but had few issues in the application.

```
  public ImageCollection Strokes
        { get { return new ImageCollection(); } }   //< 6.0
```

Kindly help. Also is there any way to convert these? Often i get solutions in `6.0` which i have to downgrade.

Comment: I will do this in constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not the same.

In the first example you have a property which will be instantiated through the constructor.

In the second example you return a new instance every time you access the property.

The correct refactor looks like this:

```
public ImageCollection Strokes
{ 
    get; private set; 
} 

public constructor() 
{
    Strokes = new ImageCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are going to have to assign the property in your constructor.

Option 1 - A property with a private setter:

```
class Example
{
    public ImageCollection Strokes { get; private set; }

    public Example()
    {
        Strokes = new ImageCollection();
    }
}
```

Option 2 - A property with a getter only, backed by a private readonly field:

```
class Example
{
    public ImageCollection Strokes { get { return _strokes; } }

    private readonly ImageCollection _strokes;

    public Example()
    {
        _strokes = new ImageCollection();
    }
}
```

Option 3 - Like option 2, but assigning the field inline instead of in the constructor:

```
class Example
{
    public ImageCollection Strokes { get { return _strokes; } }

    private readonly ImageCollection _strokes = new ImageCollection();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a private field that the getter uses:

```
class MyClass
{
    private ImageCollection _strokes = new ImageCollection();
    public ImageCollection Strokes { get { return _strokes }  }
 }
```

Or you could initialize it in the constructor.

```
class MyClass
{
    public ImageCollection Strokes { get; private set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
          Strokes = new ImageCollection();
    }
}
```

Just remember to initialize it in *all* constructors of the class, or at least have your other constructors call a constructor that does.

---

The problem with your solution is that it returns a new instance of `ImageCollection` each time `get` is called. This produces multiple that have nothing to do with each other. Changing one will not change the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what issues you arr facing but change code like below
your code always creating the new object , **but 6.0 one time initialization**
Try

```
var imgCollection = new ImageCollection(); 

public ImageCollection Strokes
    { get { return imgCollection; } }   //< 6.0
```